# How to console.log data retrieved from asynchronous api call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, async-await

I'm making an API call to a server and sending to a React component. I'm trying to work out if the data has been loaded successfully and how it looks once it is loaded.

However, when I `console.log` the data I obviously only receive a `promise` object. Does anyone know how to ensure the `console.log` only fires once the API call is complete? I've tried to use `async` and `await` although I've struggled to get it working.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// actions
import { getPlayers, deletePlayer } from '../actions'
// components
import RenderPlayer from './RenderPlayer'

class DeletePlayer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.players = null
    this.renderPlayerList = null
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.players = this.props.getPlayers()

    this.renderPlayerList = () => {
      //map over each player entry in database and send all details as props to rednderPlayer
      this.players = this.players.map((player) => { return <RenderPlayer {...player} /> })

      return this.players
    }

    console.log(this.players)

    return this.players
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.players}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { getPlayers, deletePlayer })(DeletePlayer)
```

Comment: For understanding `async` and `await` take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn3tm0quoqE

Comment: `.then(console.log)`

Comment: I think you're looking for `this.players = await this.props.getPlayers();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `this.players` returns a promise, you can use `.then()` to do something with its response.

```
this.players.then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with `async` and `await` and a little clean up:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { getPlayers, deletePlayer } from '../actions'

import RenderPlayer from './RenderPlayer'

class DeletePlayer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: [],
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    const { getPlayers } = this.props

    try {
      const players = await getPlayers()

      console.log(players)

      this.setState({ players })
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { players } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        {players.map(player => <RenderPlayer {...player} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { getPlayers, deletePlayer })(DeletePlayer)
```